# invalid reference format when building a Docker Image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following lines in a Dockerfile:

```
ARG SOMEARGUMENT
COPY --from=$SOMEARGUMENT /some/path/goes/here
```

where SOMEARGUMENT could be either "some/repository:1.1.1" or "some/repository:2.2.2"

But when trying to build I always get the error:

```
invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

So it is obvious that the argument passed when building the image (i.e. SOMEARGUMENT) is not being resolved.

Is it actaully possible to do something like this in a Dockerfile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you always base on the same repo, it's cleaner to do like this.

```
ARG VERSION
FROM some/repository:${VERSION} as builder
RUN mkdir test
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /test /
```

Source:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: interesting. I was not aware of this behavior. Can you point me to the documentation on how this can be used? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Siyu for your answer. I just tested it , but it is not working. I removed the FROM scratch instructions and I am making another test, but at least I see some progress in the console output. Do you know why is this "FROM scratch" instruction there?

Comment: @eindemwort you can't remove the second `FROM `: these 2 `FROM` are forming a multi-stage build which enables you to do `COPY --from`. I'm using `FROM scratch` just to make this point, it doesn't have to be it, a common last stage could be `FROM alpine` which is a small linux image. It will be helpful if you tell us why do you want this kind of behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Siyu! Your help was very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Siyu answer.

A possible solution to your questions can be the following:

Dockerfile:

```
ARG SOMEARGUMENT
ARG SOMEVERSION=latest

FROM ${SOMEARGUMENT}:${SOMEVERSION} as thebase
RUN echo "This is a test" > /test.txt


FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=thebase /test.txt /success.txt

CMD cat /success.txt
```

Command to build:

```
docker build --build-arg SOMEARGUMENT=alpine --tag test .
```